# Validation failed: Password can't be blank when editing a user in Rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, devise

I've generated a User model via Devise, and added a new user with password `12345678`. It looks like this:

```
development environment > User.first
=> #<User id: 1, email: "a@n", created_at: "2021-10-27 16:32:37.895722000 +0000",
updated_at: "2021-10-27 16:32:37.895722000 +0000", user_type: "user">
```

and I want to manually set this user to admin. I do this:

```
development environment > user = User.first
development environment > user.user_type = "admin"
development environment > user.save!
```

and after this I get the following message: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Password can't be blank)`

My user model (`user.rb`) in ActiveRecord is this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates :email, :password, presence: true
  validates :password, length: {in: 5..15}, on: :create

  user_types = ['user', 'moderator', 'admin']
  validates :user_type, inclusion: { in: user_types }
end
```

what is the problem? I am not creating any new users, and the password was entered correctly during registration. How to fix this?

Comment: remove your password validations from your model. You already included `validatable` devise module - and that will validate your password on its own.

Comment: @BroiSatse what if I want some specific validations? Can I override those provided by `validatable ` ?

Comment: Depends on the validations you want to add. Generally speaking it is not easy to override existing validation, but you could just skip `vlaidatable` module and add your own - but then bare in mind you need to be very careful with those validations. For example right now you're validating presence of password on each save and its format only on create - so user would be able to update their password to 1 character. In your case however you could just change `Devise.password_length` configuration